# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.bordeaux.contactapp.Exceptions.AuthenticationException after renaming package

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, package, classnotfoundexception

I move/rename the package where my servlet are and I get this error :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.bordeaux.contactapp.Exceptions.AuthenticationException

I'm new to Eclipse and Java. I undo the rename but errors persist.
Everybody have an idea that I have to do ?

Thanks for your help.

There are the trace here :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/bordeaux/contactapp/Exceptions/AuthenticationException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5053)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.bordeaux.contactapp.Exceptions.AuthenticationException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 20 more
```

[image: Director]

Comment: please post your web.xml

Comment: Is AuthentificationException in your exceptions package?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an older version of Tomcat, so this may or may not help.

Check for a file named web.xml within the WEB-INF folder.  I'm using Netbeans, so for me it's under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF - Eclipse may place it elsewhere.

Within that file, you specify the classes used to run your servlet or filter.  It's possible that your refactor did not modify the contents of the web.xml file.

Good luck!

Comment: Thks. Maybe can be that, but I create a new Dynamic Web Project and copy paste all code....

Answer (score 0):

What you need to focus on in your error stacktrace is :
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/bordeaux/contactapp/Exceptions/AuthenticationException

Is seems that you are still referencing the class AuthenticationException
In the package fr.bordeaux.contactapp.Exceptions
And this class doesn't exist there...

PS1: java is case sensitive 
Ps2: by convention, packages in Java are lowercase

Comment: Thks. Maybe can be that, but I create a new Dynamic Web Project and copy paste all code....

Answer (score 0):

in my case the error was fixed by adding "/" in url-pattern ,which i forgot to use.After adding "/" the server started successfully. eg

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>imp_servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/implement_servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```